# How to use two blockchains for the same application?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, hyperledger-indy

Can we use two blockchains such that one blockchain is permissioned and other is permissionless for some application so that one blockchain can be used to have private data and the other is used to store public data for verification?

I am not checking for interoperabilty..

for example, In process of buying a car, The buyer actually buys it from dealer and the buyer do not want his details plus car details(buyer id, VIN, engine number,car make,...) to be put onto public blockchain except the fact that a particular car model is sold to some blockchain address. So using private chain between RTO and Dealer, if dealer uploads details(buyer id, VIN, engine number,car make,...) onto private chain then RTO can verify the owner of the car.

Comment: You can store your private data into a separate side database while your blockchain ledger/database will contain the hash value of your private data.

Different blockchain platform have different architecture for resolving this situation. So far Hyperledger Fabric is considered as the most popular blockchain platform for private and permissioned blockchain framework.

You can check the following link for better understanding: https://medium.com/coinmonks/private-public-data-at-hyperledger-fabric-v1-4-ff9f303f4bc1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any number of blockchains within an application.

Blockchain is just used for the following operations:

1. Query the contents of a ledger.
2. Submit transactions to a ledger.
3. Computations using a smart contract.

You just need to take care of the endpoints at the application level or in the smart contract to perform write and query operations.

Interchain communication is a different problem altogether.